# Cocos2d 2.x, 1.x and ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting

I had choosen Cocos2d v1.01rc instead of 2.x when starting developing my first game two months ago.

Now that I am learning more I realized that ARC is fully supported and integrated in Cocos2d 2.x and instead in v1.01rc I have to decide whether to disable or enable it (see [tinytimgames post](http://www.tinytimgames.com/2011/07/22/cocos2d-and-arc/)) for the entire project or just Cocos2d files.

I choose version 1.01 as I did not need OpenGL ES 2.0 features ([see this comparison guide](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/01/choosing-cocos2d-version-updating-cocos2d-2-0/)) but now that I found out that ARC is better supported in Cocos2d 2.x I feel a bit stupid as it does seem to me that Cocos2d 2.0 is the way forward for new games.

See quote: "cocos2d v2.0 is, like v1.1, ARC compliant, but doesn't uses ARC internally. But at some point, v2.0 will be migrated to ARC internally (cocos2d v2.0 uses blocks internally, but not ARC)." in [cocos2d forum post](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/28805%22) (It mentions cocos2d v2.0 and not v1.x, so I assume the contribution focus of developers is on v2.0 and v1.x will have fewer people to maintain it). **Is this correct?** That's a big reason to use Coco2d 2.x for new projects to me!!

I started developing my game 2 months ago but I am being pretty slow as I am learning in the meanwhile and I could still be on time to move to 2.x.

Any suggestions? What should I do?

1. disable ARC
2. enable ARC
3. move to Cocos2d 2.x

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards disabling or enabling ARC it all depends on how comfortable you feel with handling your own memory allocation and deallocation.

The only reason you might not want to use ARC is your game would only be supported by devices running iOS 5 and above, however the adoption rate seems quite high so i would not necessarily rule out using ARC

***Edited***

Having a look over the release notes for cocos2d v2 it seems a lot of outstanding issues have been fixed and the addition of ARC support seems beneficial as well. If i was starting out i would probably go for the latest stable version

This link should help with migrating from v1 to v2

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:migrate_to_v2.0

Comment: This link will help if you want to enable ARC http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enabling-arc-cocos2d-project-howto-stepbystep-tutorialguide/

Comment: thanks for the link, I was actually watching Steffen's video right now :) http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enable-arc-cocos2d-project-video-tutorial/ ..could you edit your answer adding also your thoughts on whether I should use 2.x or 1.x? Thanks!

Comment: I dont really feel like i can make that call, both have pro's and con's and i am happy to help make a list of these to help you decide. I personally am still using v1.1 but thats personally because i have made changes in my cocos2d source base that i have not  migrated across to v2 yet

Comment: Thanks J.,a list of these would help me a lot, thanks! I am aiming to release my game in about 5-6 months (so probably after iPhone 5 will have been released), hence I am not targeting devices with no OpenGL 2 support.. I am learning a lot but I am struggling keeping peace with all those changes and I do not want to spend my days configuring my work environment.. (e.g. for now I keep Xcode 4.2 and I haven't installed iOS 6 yet as I think is not strictly necessary for the features of my game). But my gut instict says that I should probably move to 2.x as it is the future.. any random thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for accepting. I understand the issues of getting bogged down with trying to keep you dev environment up-to-date. With such a short turn around for a game (5-6 months) very little will change so taking cocos2d v2 as your base version is a good starting point. In the past cocos2d has had quite a few memory leaks especially with areas such as font label so any bug fixes and enhancements to memory usage will save you a lot of time in the debugging/testing/memory profiling stage of development. Good Luck with the game

Comment: ARC is for iOS 4.x onward!!!  It's backwards compatible.  There is NO REASON for anyone not to use ARC at this point, it is insane not to.

Answer (score 3):

For new users I definitely recommend using ARC (actually I recommend that to everyone).

Unless you really have to support 1st and 2nd generation devices, go for cocos2d 2.0. In this breakdown you'll find that [OpenGL ES 1.1 devices market share gets smaller and smaller](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/03/ios-sales-statistics-q1-2012-split-by-model-opengl-es-2-0-support/), and right now it's almost negligible - especially if you consider the additional development time (equals cost) necessary to test your game with even the oldest devices and possibly optimize performance for older devices.

Here are some additional [points to consider choosing between cocos2d 1.x and 2.x](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/01/choosing-cocos2d-version-updating-cocos2d-2-0/). And of course [how to enable ARC in cocos2d](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enabling-arc-cocos2d-project-howto-stepbystep-tutorialguide/). And lastly, how not to bother and [just start using ARC with Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com) (v2.0 is coming soon).

Comment: Thanks Steffen, is always an honour to receive answers from you (having your book on my desk). I had posted some of the links in your answer in my original question as I hadn't fully clear at the time of reading your article (3 months ago) that Apple had introduced ARC in WWDC '11 (I am a new iOS dev). In short, I am also a bit reluctant to use Kobold as I want to fully learn Cocos2d first and I have the gut feeling that the number of people contributing to Cocos2d source code is higher. Would be nice if you could convince them to integrate Kobold in Cocos2d :) to merge the developer community

Comment: sorry for my previous comment. I clarified what actually Kobold2d in the cocos2d-iphone forum and I now appreciate that Kobold2d WON'T split the community and instead is more likely to benefit to Cocos2d. So thank you for your suggestion and please accept my apologies for misunderstanding your project.